# Microsoft word page numbering resets at 99 and goes back to 1. How to fix it?

Tags: microsoft-word

The so the sequence of page number is from 1 to 99 and then it goes back again to 1. i wonder if I could just go in the page 100 and start a new numbering sequence customized starting from 100 to fix this issue.

Comment: This question is lacking details. Have you tried anything? Did you try what you wondered? Is so, what happened? What version of Word are you using? We cannot help without any details.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things can cause page numbering to reset.  The first thing I would try is locating each section break and setting the section to "Continue page numbering from previous section".  One thing that commonly causes new sections to be created is the use of columns.   Your question needs more information in order to provide the best answer.